# Does Java call an abstract classe's constructor automatically?

Tags: java, object, constructor, abstract-class, subclass

Say I've made an abstract class called animal, and then I make a subclass called dogs which extends animal. The animal class has a constructor method written inside. If I decide to instantiate a "dog" object, will the animal classes's constructor automatically be called as well?

If someone could clarify, and further expand on this a bit, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  could you please validate my post below. somebody downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , The constructor of an abstract class can be called. why not?  Use super() from subclass to call the super class argument constructor(s). If you dont use super(), then by default the no-arg constructor of super class will be called.

If you call

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
```

By default the super class default constructor[no-arg constructor] will be called.

If you call

```
Dog dog = new Dog("doggie1");
```

<s>Unless you explicitly call super() inside the one argument constructor of `Dog`, the default super class constructor will not be called.</s>

Try it..

Edit: ***If you don't call super() inside the one argument constructor of `Dog`, then also the default super class constructor will be called***.

*If you want to explicitly call the argument constructor , say one argument constructor of the super class, you have to explicitly make the call `super("value");`*

```
Animal() {
        System.out.println("Animal superconstructor");
    }
```

**Edit 02:**

*Sample program and output*

(1)

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    SubClass(String str) {
        super(str);
    }

    SubClass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass("hello");
    }
}

abstract class SuperClass {
    SuperClass() {
        System.out.println("I am SuperClass()");
    }

    SuperClass(String str) {
        System.out.println("I am SuperClass(String str)");
    }
}
```

> //output: I am SuperClass(String str)

(2)

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    SubClass(String str) {
    }

    SubClass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass("hello");
    }
}

abstract class SuperClass {
    SuperClass() {
        System.out.println("I am SuperClass()");
    }

    SuperClass(String str) {
        System.out.println("I am SuperClass(String str)");
    }
}
```

> //output: I am SuperClass()

(3)

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    SubClass(String str) {
    }

    SubClass() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SubClass();
    }
}

abstract class SuperClass {
    SuperClass() {
        System.out.println("I am SuperClass()");
    }

    SuperClass(String str) {
        System.out.println("I am SuperClass(String str)");
    }
}
```

> // output: I am SuperClass()

Comment: I've been looking for clarification. Java has stupid constructor inheritance

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the abstract class's constructor (only the default constructor) is called by default only in the instance of the default constructor. To call the other constructors of the inherited class, a super() call needs to be made inside the constructors of the subclass.

Comment: So if I placed a method called super() within the constructor of my subclasses constructor, that would do the trick? What parameters does super() take?

Comment: @Vimzy super() (for constructors) takes whatever parameters the constructor of the inherited class takes. So if you want to add some work to the subclass's constructor, but still call the constructor of the abstract class, using `super()` with the arguments of the abstract class's constructor will do the trick.

Comment: no constructor defined for subclass? ok, you updated as no no-arg constructor.. cool

Comment: even if you don't explicity call super() from subclass default constructor, the super class default constructor will be called

Comment: What I mean is that if the sub class does not define a 0 argument constructor, and it also fails to call the inherited class's constructor through the super() function, the inherited class's constructor will be used when an object of the subclass is created with no arguments.

Comment: @prash So it still calls the super() even if it isn't actually written in code?

Comment: infact what you meant in comments is correct, but what you posted is not correct.

Comment: the second part is not valid " the abstract class's constructor (only the no argument constructor) is called only if there isn't a no-argument constructor defined for the sub class or the subclass's constructor uses the super keyword super() to call the abstract class's constructor".

Comment: Alright, thanks for correcting my answer. Let me edit me answer

Answer (score 1):

If `Animal` has a no-arg constructor, then `Animal`'s subclasses will call it automatically. Otherwise, the compiler will complain. In such a case, you have to call `super()` explicitly with the appropriate parameters for the `Animal` constructor you wish to use.